# How to trigger open a jQuery UI dialog from a separate page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm not very good with jQuery and I've hit a wall recently. I have a jQuery UI dialog that opens when a user triggers it on index.html. It is hidden on index.html until the user triggers it open. On another page that's a separate html page, I have a button that links you back to index.html, but what I need to do is when a user clicks on this link it will take them back to index.html and will trigger the dialog modal window to open automatically.

I have it working to some extent, but I wanted to find an alternative solution where I'm not using the URL to make it work.

The HTML of the "go back" link

```
<a href="index.html#dialog">Go back</a>
```

My jQuery:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#dialog") != -1) {

$('.dialog-popup').dialog("open"); 

}
```

The jQuery of the UI pop up:

```
$( ".dialog-popup" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: 860,
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 500
  }
});
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I want it to work without having to put the #dialog in the URL.

Comment: You could set a cookie, and index.html could check for this cookie and open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.referrer` to determine where the user came from. If you parse document.referrer for information regarding the page the user came from and match it against something, you could trigger the dialog that way.

For instance, if you want to trigger the dialog whenever a user arrives at index.html from a page that's on your domain, but not from index.html itself, you could run this code:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var referrerDomain = document.referrer.replace(/(http|https):\/\//,'').split("/")[0];
    var myDomain = "mydomain.net"; //Your domain name goes here
    if( referrerDomain == myDomain && !document.referrer.match("index.html") )
        alert('You arrived at this page from your domain, but not from index.html!')

});
```

as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/v9fq5/2/) (full screen version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/v9fq5/2/embedded/result/))

Note - the fiddles will show the referrer as the same page you're currently on. This won't happen on a normal page; it's just happening there because it's using iFrames.

Comment: I agree with this , it can be a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about writing this, could you help me out?

Comment: Edited my post with more info