# Open jQuery dialog from previous page

Tags: php, jquery, html, dialog

This may sound vague, I apologise for that. But I can't seem to find anything or anyone that's trying to do the same as me.

Although, I've just seen [How to trigger open a jQuery UI dialog from a separate page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660191/how-to-trigger-open-a-jquery-ui-dialog-from-a-separate-page) but I'm not sure that would strictly work.

I have a single profile page for members with the data driven by an XML feed. On the profile page is a link that opens a jQuery dialog box. This is working fine.

Elsewhere on the site, is another page that generates a list of members depending on a filter, with a link to that users profile. Also on this other page, with the list of members, is a duplicate link to the jQuery dialog box.

How can I make this duplicate link go to the profile page and automatically fire the jQuery dialog box to open?

Answer (score 0):

My way to do this is to use Hash part of URL

for example your URL to profile from other page should be like this

```
profile#showdlg
```

and in profile page

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
                if(hash == "showdlg"){
                     //Show dialog here
                 }
```

And this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (should not) directly trigger some script action in a page "to be loaded in future". Instead the trigger should be part of the page itself.

So if that profile page is generated in a dynamical way an approach would be to implement a conditional feature that adds such trigger (like using jquery to fire the dialog when the dom tree is ready, there are millions of examples for that). The condition would be whether the profile page has been called via such a special reference or not. You could detect that by looking at the HTTP-REFERER. So it boils down to: if called in a specific way, then add a 2-lines-of-code trigger to the profile page that initially fires the dialog.

To answer your comment below here some more detailed description:

There is not much coding involved. The links reference the users profile pages. The profile pages are generated by php I assume. So all you need to add is one detail: inside php check if the request currently processed has a certain referer it was raised from:

```
<?php .... if ('other_page.php'==$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]) { ... } ... ?>
```

If so you know that the profile page was called from that other page instead of the normal situation, so you want the UI dialog to fire by itself. For this you add a tiny javascript to the generated page which does the trick as soon as the page has loaded:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#mydialog').raise();})</script>
```

The details obviously depend on what type of dialog and how it is raised. But you should get the idea of what I suggest...

Comment: That sounds quite like what I'm after. Are you able to break that down at all? in terms of coding examples?